# SSRS report email delivery subscription failure

Tags: reporting-services, report, subscription

I have a report and when I tried to create a subscription for email delivery to my address, I have received a status message as

> Failure sending mail:An error has occured during report processing.

What can be the possible reasons of this message.
The report works fine normally, is since it failed due to some reason the error message is?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your report has parameters which can't be filled in when sending a mail.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the e-mail preferences are set up correctly?  Does your SMTP server allow relaying from the SSRS machine?  Can you send any other e-mails from the SSRS machine?